# Host VPN on a allways on machine with dynamic IP

Tags: vpn

Is it possible to host a VPN sevice on a dynamic IP machine?
I'm trying to do this by myself. I'm not a pro in networks. I just can recognize RJ-45 from RJ-11 and setup an ad-hoc network and stuff like this. I want to host my own VPN server on my Window machine. Is there any special software to host VPN? Is not having static IP a problem?

Thanks in advance

I'm using Windows 7 Premium

Comment: Asking this is like "Is it possible to modify a webpage with Javascript?" We answer "yes". And in the comments you want a step by step, best practices and what to avoid guide. Seriously?

Comment: No, it's like asking how to make a paragraph clickable in JavaScript and answer is yes and step by step guide is just 10 line.

Comment: You are lazy to answer the question and close the question.

Comment: Looks like I'm blind. I can't see a "How?" in the original or the edited question. And asking Google the "How"-question would lead to plenty results.

Comment: There's nothing quite like insulting the people volunteering their time to help you that gets good results. Some advice: The effort people will take answering your question is proportional to the effort you put forth in asking it. Also, don't take closing/down-voting personally.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Sure.

You would probably need to set up some kind of [Dynamic DNS](http://www.no-ip.org) in order to be able to *find* the machine when you want to connect to it, and you may need to do something special to the VPN software if it expects to see a static address (depends on what you're using).